# how to store user-specific data through chrome extension

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension that, through an XMLHttpRequest, sends some variable values on a .php file which inserts these data to a mySQL database.

In addition to this data, I also want to get user-specific information (a unique user_id for example) that will allow me to connect every piece of data to the user that generated it.

My question is: Is this possible through a chrome extension, and if it is, can you please give me some pointers on where to start looking?

Thank you very much!

P.S: I do not want to have the actual identities of the users, I just want to be able to differentiate data that came from different users.

Comment: first time the extension is loaded you could create a guid (or query your php file to request an id) and store it in chrome.storage. I cannot think of another way. You could store it in chrome.storage.sync so that that user would have the same ID even when logged into chrome on another computer.

Comment: Would the identity api solve your problem? 

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

Comment: Thanks @Gravitate, I have used chrome.storage and it worked, but, coupled with my inexperience, I found it very inconvenient. I came back to it, more than 1 year later and I think steven's answer (the identity api) is the way to go now. Thank you both, I upvoted both comments because they were both useful to me.

Comment: @steven if you post it as an answer I will accept it for other users to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity api is probably the answer in this case
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity